# Postgresql shows slow query but low execution time in analyzed output

Tags: postgresql, sql-execution-plan

Postgresql Version: 13.6
Server size: 2cx4g

Logs of Postgresql shows duration `6215.926ms`, but explain shows that the execution time and planning time are less than `200ms`

Is slow reading speed of the client a cause of the problem?

```
2022-04-18 16:28:20.491 CST [1159] LOG:  duration: 6215.926 ms  statement: EXPLAIN (ANALYZE ON, BUFFERS ON) select 1 from information_schema.tables where table_schema = 'pg_catalog' and table_name = 'pg_file_settings'
Nested Loop  (cost=0.68..17.88 rows=1 width=4) (actual time=0.126..0.128 rows=1 loops=1)
  Join Filter: (c.relnamespace = nc.oid)
  Buffers: shared hit=8 read=2
  I/O Timings: read=0.027
  ->  Nested Loop Left Join  (cost=0.68..16.81 rows=1 width=4) (actual time=0.085..0.087 rows=1 loops=1)
        Buffers: shared hit=3 read=2
        I/O Timings: read=0.027
        ->  Index Scan using pg_class_relname_nsp_index on pg_class c  (cost=0.27..8.33 rows=1 width=8) (actual time=0.065..0.066 rows=1 loops=1)
              Index Cond: (relname = 'pg_file_settings'::name)
              Filter: ((relkind = ANY ('{r,v,f,p}'::"char"[])) AND (pg_has_role(relowner, 'USAGE'::text) OR has_table_privilege(oid, 'SELECT, INSERT, UPDATE, DELETE, TRUNCATE, REFERENCES, TRIGGER'::text) OR has_any_column_privilege(oid, 'SELECT, INSERT, UPDATE, REFERENCES'::text)))
              Buffers: shared hit=1 read=2
              I/O Timings: read=0.027
        ->  Nested Loop  (cost=0.40..8.47 rows=1 width=4) (actual time=0.017..0.018 rows=0 loops=1)
              Buffers: shared hit=2
              ->  Index Scan using pg_type_oid_index on pg_type t  (cost=0.27..8.29 rows=1 width=8) (actual time=0.016..0.016 rows=0 loops=1)
                    Index Cond: (oid = c.reloftype)
                    Buffers: shared hit=2
              ->  Index Only Scan using pg_namespace_oid_index on pg_namespace nt  (cost=0.13..0.17 rows=1 width=4) (never executed)
                    Index Cond: (oid = t.typnamespace)
                    Heap Fetches: 0
  ->  Seq Scan on pg_namespace nc  (cost=0.00..1.06 rows=1 width=4) (actual time=0.038..0.038 rows=1 loops=1)
        Filter: ((NOT pg_is_other_temp_schema(oid)) AND (nspname = 'pg_catalog'::name))
        Rows Removed by Filter: 1
        Buffers: shared hit=5
Planning:
  Buffers: shared hit=168 read=52 written=5
  I/O Timings: read=103.513 write=43.230
Planning Time: 184.492 ms
Execution Time: 0.438 ms
```

**Edit**:
After running `analyze` on the database, same results:

```
2022-04-18 17:53:04.563 CST [16398] LOG:  duration: 5987.077 ms  statement: EXPLAIN (ANALYZE ON, BUFFERS ON) select 1 from information_schema.tables where table_schema = 'pg_catalog' and table_name = 'pg_file_settings'
Nested Loop  (cost=0.68..17.88 rows=1 width=4) (actual time=0.125..0.127 rows=1 loops=1)
  Join Filter: (c.relnamespace = nc.oid)
  Buffers: shared hit=8 read=2
  I/O Timings: read=0.025
  ->  Nested Loop Left Join  (cost=0.68..16.81 rows=1 width=4) (actual time=0.088..0.090 rows=1 loops=1)
        Buffers: shared hit=3 read=2
        I/O Timings: read=0.025
        ->  Index Scan using pg_class_relname_nsp_index on pg_class c  (cost=0.27..8.33 rows=1 width=8) (actual time=0.069..0.070 rows=1 loops=1)
              Index Cond: (relname = 'pg_file_settings'::name)
              Filter: ((relkind = ANY ('{r,v,f,p}'::"char"[])) AND (pg_has_role(relowner, 'USAGE'::text) OR has_table_privilege(oid, 'SELECT, INSERT, UPDATE, DELETE, TRUNCATE, REFERENCES, TRIGGER'::text) OR has_any_column_privilege(oid, 'SELECT, INSERT, UPDATE, REFERENCES'::text)))
              Buffers: shared hit=1 read=2
              I/O Timings: read=0.025
        ->  Nested Loop  (cost=0.40..8.47 rows=1 width=4) (actual time=0.016..0.016 rows=0 loops=1)
              Buffers: shared hit=2
              ->  Index Scan using pg_type_oid_index on pg_type t  (cost=0.27..8.29 rows=1 width=8) (actual time=0.014..0.014 rows=0 loops=1)
                    Index Cond: (oid = c.reloftype)
                    Buffers: shared hit=2
              ->  Index Only Scan using pg_namespace_oid_index on pg_namespace nt  (cost=0.13..0.17 rows=1 width=4) (never executed)
                    Index Cond: (oid = t.typnamespace)
                    Heap Fetches: 0
  ->  Seq Scan on pg_namespace nc  (cost=0.00..1.06 rows=1 width=4) (actual time=0.035..0.035 rows=1 loops=1)
        Filter: ((NOT pg_is_other_temp_schema(oid)) AND (nspname = 'pg_catalog'::name))
        Rows Removed by Filter: 1
        Buffers: shared hit=5
Planning:
  Buffers: shared hit=170 read=59 written=9
  I/O Timings: read=105.688 write=79.773
Planning Time: 262.826 ms
Execution Time: 0.366 ms
```

Edit:
Analyze output after increasing `shared_buffers` to 25% of memory

```
Nested Loop  (cost=0.68..17.88 rows=1 width=4) (actual time=0.096..0.098 rows=1 loops=1)
  Join Filter: (c.relnamespace = nc.oid)
  Buffers: shared hit=10
  ->  Nested Loop Left Join  (cost=0.68..16.81 rows=1 width=4) (actual time=0.057..0.059 rows=1 loops=1)
        Buffers: shared hit=5
        ->  Index Scan using pg_class_relname_nsp_index on pg_class c  (cost=0.27..8.33 rows=1 width=8) (actual time=0.040..0.042 rows=1 loops=1)
              Index Cond: (relname = 'pg_file_settings'::name)
              Filter: ((relkind = ANY ('{r,v,f,p}'::"char"[])) AND (pg_has_role(relowner, 'USAGE'::text) OR has_table_privilege(oid, 'SELECT, INSERT, UPDATE, DELETE, TRUNCATE, REFERENCES, TRIGGER'::text) OR has_any_column_privilege(oid, 'SELECT, INSERT, UPDATE, REFERENCES'::text)))
              Buffers: shared hit=3
        ->  Nested Loop  (cost=0.40..8.47 rows=1 width=4) (actual time=0.014..0.014 rows=0 loops=1)
              Buffers: shared hit=2
              ->  Index Scan using pg_type_oid_index on pg_type t  (cost=0.27..8.29 rows=1 width=8) (actual time=0.012..0.012 rows=0 loops=1)
                    Index Cond: (oid = c.reloftype)
                    Buffers: shared hit=2
              ->  Index Only Scan using pg_namespace_oid_index on pg_namespace nt  (cost=0.13..0.17 rows=1 width=4) (never executed)
                    Index Cond: (oid = t.typnamespace)
                    Heap Fetches: 0
  ->  Seq Scan on pg_namespace nc  (cost=0.00..1.06 rows=1 width=4) (actual time=0.036..0.036 rows=1 loops=1)
        Filter: ((NOT pg_is_other_temp_schema(oid)) AND (nspname = 'pg_catalog'::name))
        Rows Removed by Filter: 1
        Buffers: shared hit=5
Planning:
  Buffers: shared hit=229
Planning Time: 7.866 ms
Execution Time: 0.306 ms
```

Comment: When did you update your statistics last time?

Comment: @D-Shih is it a good method of updating statistics by running `analyze` on the database?

Comment: The execution time can also be affected by other transactions. For example, slow transactions can set locks that delay the execution of this query.

Comment: Is each of your formatted blocks one log message, or did you piece it together from other sources?  What are your log settings?

Comment: I don't think that the client can be the problem. But your slow planning time is curious: do you have extremely bloated catalog tables? Or is `default_statistics_target` set to 10000?

Comment: @LaurenzAlbe Hi, value of `the default_statistics_target `  is 100.

Comment: The slow query disappears after increasing  value of `shared_buffers` from `16MB` to `1GB`(25% of RAM). But the number in the logs is still confusing, it only took 184ms in the `I/O Timings` row.

Comment: @LaurenzAlbe What do you mean by extremely bloated catalog tables?

Comment: I meant catalog tables that contain a lot of empty space, probably because of many metadata changes. But having a tiny `shared_buffers` may well cause the same effect that the catalogs don't fit into the cache. So yes, choose a sensible value for `shared_buffers`. However, i have no explanation for the observed difference between logged duration and `EXPLAIN (ANALYZE)` output.